# AWS Glue classifier for multi-delimiter not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-glue, logstash-grok

I am trying to run a crawler on CSV file located in s3 where |~| is the delimiter. I gave the delimiter as below:

[image: custom classifier]

I ran the crawler but it is not able to read the data and creates an empty table. I have more than 600 columns and not sure how to create a GROK pattern for this. Hive provides a way to remove multi-delimiter easily like this : 'field.delim'='|~|'
I tried to do the same using Athena but no luck.I don't want to re-process the whole file again(20GB) by using python code just to replace/remove the delimiter.

Has anyone had the same issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: it seems like not supported in glue

Answer (score 0):

Multichar delimiters are not supported in glue as well as spark.

Delimiter must be one character only.

Comment: Spark does support multichar delimiter.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24540

Comment: It is definitely not part of spark 2.4